# How can I resolve the error Attempting to load class "MockStorageStrategy"?

Tags: php, api, symfony, mangopay

I'm stuck on an error that I can't solve, I need help please.

Attempted to load class "MockStorageStrategy" from namespace "MangoPay\Tests\Mocks".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

[image: error message]

my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
use App\Entity\User;
use MangoPay;
use MangoPay\Tests\Mocks\MockStorageStrategy;

class CallApiService
{
    private $mangoPayApi;
    private $client;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient)
    {
        $this->client = $httpClient;
        $this->mangoPayApi = new MangoPay\MangoPayApi();
        $this->mangoPayApi->Config->ClientId = $_ENV['CLIENT_ID'];
        $this->mangoPayApi->Config->ClientPassword = $_ENV['API_KEY'];
        // $this->mangoPayApi->Config->TemporaryFolder = '/some/path/';
        $this->mangoPayApi->OAuthTokenManager->RegisterCustomStorageStrategy(new MockStorageStrategy());
        //$this->mangoPayApi->Config->BaseUrl = 'https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com';
    }

    public function createProfilMango($form)
    {
        $userMango = $this->client->request(
            'POST',
            'https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com/v2.01/' . '%env(CLIENT_ID)%' . '/users/natural',
            [
                $UserNatural = new MangoPay\UserNatural(),
                $UserNatural->FirstName = $form['firstname']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->LastName = $form['lastname']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->Email = $form['email']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->Address = new \MangoPay\Address(),
                $UserNatural->Address->AddressLine1 = $form['streetNumber']->getData() . $form['address']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->Address->AddressLine2 = "",
                $UserNatural->Address->City = $form['city']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->Address->Region = "",
                $UserNatural->Address->PostalCode = $form['zipCode']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->Address->Country = "FR",
                $UserNatural->Birthday = $form['birthday']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->Nationality = $form['nationality']->getData(),
                $UserNatural->CountryOfResidence = "FR",
                $Result = $this->mangoPayApi->Users->Create($UserNatural),
            ]
        );

        return $userMango;
    }
}
```

The namespace has been checked and it is correct, concerning the dependencies the http-client and mangopay/php-sdk-v2 have been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using classes from a `Test` namespace are sometimes not added to the autoloader - as you should not use them in your application. A look at that package's [`composer.json`](https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk/blob/3.11.0/composer.json) shows this: the namespace `MangoPay` is routed to the folder `MangoPay` (see `autoload` for this), while the class you want to use is stored in another folder and loaded only through `autoload-dev`. This section is not evaluated in case you are solely using this package in your own application.

If you **really** want to use that class `MockStorageStrategy` (which is only provided for the package's internal test suite, not for being used by the application!), you should copy it to your own application namespace.